# Send selected text to festival

Tags: linux, bash

How do you send currently selected text to an application like festival? There was a video tutorial I watched a long time ago which explained how but I can no longer find it.

Comment: What's your goal, how work your tool? Festival use `tcp socket` by default on port 1314... Is this what you're searching for? Please rewrite your ask!

Comment: @techno Sorry I didn't reply for so long. My goal for this is to simply press a hot key with text selected and have festival speak it.

Answer (score 2):

### Festival and inter process communication via ***TCP***

Festival work in *server mode* by opening a TCP port to listen on (by default port 1314).

You could run (on GNU/Linux system):

```
netstat -tanp | grep LISTEN
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address   State    PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22        0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN   485/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1314      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN   28442/festival
```

So I'm sure Festival server is running and use TCP port 1314.

(If festival is not present here, you may have to run `festival --server` in another console)

#### Reading docs

Each kind of ***server*** do use his own *protocol*. For a web server (on port 80) the protocol is well documented. For specifics tools, like *festival* you have to refer to original documentation.

#### TCP Communication labs.

For testing TCP connection, there is a wonderfull *swiss-knife* called `netcat`:

Sample use of `netcat` for accessing a web server:

```
nc google 80 <<<$'HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r'
```

This open a TCP socket to (one of) google server and send a `HEAD /` request. The answer could be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 05 Jan 2014 08:59:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Mon, 03 Jun 2013 08:07:06 GMT
ETag: "48b79-1b4e-4de3b73517e80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 6990
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

To send a request to festival, you have to use `LISP` syntaxe, and send your script simply to the socket:

```
nc localhost 1314 <myscript >raw_output
```

or

```
nc localhost 1314 <<< "(tts_text \"Hello world\" nil)(quit)"
```

If everything work normaly, you must hear something...

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. Use `xsel` or `xclip`

```
xsel | festival --tts
```

or

```
xclip -o | festival --tts
```

This will pipe your x primary selection(currently selected text) to festival.